How to mock i18n t() in vue3/nuxt3 compositionAPI with vitest?
Given the following component:
<template>
  <WglResultList :show-sorting="true"
                 :page-title="pageTitle"
                 :sort-label="t('sortLabel')"
                 :sort-title="t('sortTitle')"
                 :filter-data="computedFilterData"
                 @emit-sorting="changeSorting"
                 @emit-display-type="changeDisplayType"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted, computed, ref } from 'vue'
import { useRoute, useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const { t, locale } = useI18n() // Destructure the 't' translation function
// ....
</script>

I tried different ways to mock t() but it just doesn't work:
import {config, shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils'
import Overview from './[...slug].vue'
import componentMock from './Overview-component.mock.js'
import {mockNuxtImport} from '@nuxt/test-utils/runtime';
import { vi } from 'vitest'

// This hoisted function will be globally replaced
const { useI18nMock } = vi.hoisted(() => {
  return {
    useI18nMock: vi.fn().mockReturnValue({ t: msg => msg, locale: 'en' }),
  }
})

vi.mock('vue-i18n', useI18nMock);

mockNuxtImport('useI18n', () => ({ t: (tKey) => tKey, locale: 'en' }))


describe('overview page', () => {
  let wrapper

  it('is a Vue instance', () => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(Overview, {

      global: {
        plugins: config.global.plugins,
        mocks: {
          t: (tKey) => tKey, // Return the key itself as a simple mock
        },
      }
    })
    expect(wrapper.vm).toBeTruthy()
  })
})

I keep getting

TypeError: $setup.t is not a function

